# List all CAAnimation attached to a SCNNode

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am writing an SCNScene to FBX exporter and would like to identify which SCNNodes have animations added to them. Specifically I am interested in explicit animations through CAAnimation.

The method [animation(forKey:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnanimatable/1524020-animation) has been deprecated and [animationKeys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnanimatable/1523610-animationkeys) seems to rely on animations being added with an optional, and arbitrary key, so I can't tell which key paths are being animated.

Is there anyway to get a list of all CAAnimation that have been attached to a SCNNode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to use something like

```
for (NSString *key in scnView.scene.rootNode.animationKeys) {
    SCNAnimationPlayer *player = [scnView.scene.rootNode animationPlayerForKey:key];
    CAAnimation *animation = [CAAnimation animationWithSCNAnimation:player.animation];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The documentation is painfully sparse.

Comment: @mnuages Sorry to bother you…… I'm struggling with a SceneKit problem could you help me out? Question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428397/confused-about-orthographic-projection-of-camera-in-scenekit